# Getting null while accessing ids of dynamically generated HTML elements using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, json

Getting null when accessing ids of dynamically generated HTML elements using javascript

I am trying to dynamically change the ids of divs and remove button appended to parent div. When user clicks on button with id removeButton2 , I want the id  of `removeButton3` to change to `removeButton2` and id of `removeButton4 to removeButton3`. 
i.e, after removing the buttons id should be updated.
But I am getting null value . I can't figure out why. 
This is the code I am using at the moment:

```
var removeButtonCounter =0;
var divCounter=0;
var addButtonClickCount=0;
$('#AddButton').on('click',function() 
{ 
  removeButtonCounter++; divCounter++;addButtonClickCount++;

  $('#diplayContainerDiv').append('<div id="divQueryDisplay'+   divCounter +'"></div><div id="removeButtonDiv"><input type="button"  value="Remove" name="removeButton" id="removeButton'+  removeButtonCounter +'"> </div>');

  $("#removeButton" + removeButtonCounter).click(function() {
    var myId = this.id; 

  var lastChar = myId.slice(-1);
  valRemoveButtonClickLastChar = lastChar;
  $(this).remove();


   var i=valRemoveButtonClickLastChar;

   while(i<=addButtonClickCount)
   {
        document.getElementById(myId).id="removeButton"+i;  // null value is being passed

        document.getElementById("divQueryDisplay"+(parseInt(i)+1)).id="divQueryDisplay"+i;   // null value is being passed here    



      i++;



     }

   });
});
```

I am getting the following message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'id' of null
```

Comment: can you share your code using the plunkr or codepen

Comment: share the html code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have:

`var myId = this.id;`

`$(this).remove();`

`document.getElementById(myId).id=...`

You're removing the element with `myID`, but then you're trying to select it again and assign to it.

I'd highly recommend not changing IDs on the fly like that, but if you really want to, it'll probably be easier to iterate over all the buttons at once:

```
document.querySelectorAll('div[id^="removeButton"]').forEach((removeButton, i) => {
  removeButton.id = 'removeButton' + i;
});
```

Comment: I don't get any error . I guess it works for me. How can I get to know if the ids are updated?.

Comment: Feel free to use `Inspect` in your browser, I guess

Comment: Can you please explain your code? I mean every id contains an int value at the end of removeButton  and  'removeButton.id ' does not contain the same. What is   =>    for  ? It is underlined in red in eclipse

Comment: It iterates over every div with an ID starting with `removeButton` and assigns each of them a new ID of `'removeButton' + i` where `i` is the current index of the loop (starting from 0). `params =>` is an arrow function from ES2015, shorthand for `function(params)` - if your editor doesn't recognize it, you should probably get a new editor. Ancient browsers don't support it, but it's widely used when writing code (use Babel to transpile later).